Override a renderer in my custom course format
Moodle 4.4 codebase contains the following file:
course\format\classes\output\local\content\section\cmlist.php
I wish to override this file and the class that it contains in a custom course format I am building.
To do this I have created a file here
course\format\MY_CUSTOM_FORMAT\classes\output\local\content\section\cmlist.php
and here is its contents:
<?php

namespace format_MY_CUSTOM_FORMAT\output\local\content\section;

use core_courseformat\output\local\content\section\cmlist as base_cmlist;


use moodle_url;
 
use stdClass;


class cmlist extends base_cmlist {
    
  
    public function __construct($a, $b, $c) {
        // Call the parent constructor
        parent::__construct($a, $b, $c);
     }

     public function export_for_template(\renderer_base $output): stdClass {
        global $USER;

        $format = $this->format;
        $section = $this->section;
        $course = $format->get_course();
        $modinfo = $format->get_modinfo();
        $user = $USER;

        $data = new stdClass();
        $data->cms = [];

        // By default, non-ajax controls are disabled but in some places like the frontpage
        // it is necessary to display them. This is a temporal solution while JS is still
        // optional for course editing.
        $showmovehere = ismoving($course->id);

        if ($showmovehere) {
            $data->hascms = true;
            $data->showmovehere = true;
            $data->strmovefull = strip_tags(get_string("movefull", "", "'$user->activitycopyname'"));
            $data->movetosectionurl = new moodle_url('/course/mod.php', ['movetosection' => $section->id, 'sesskey' => sesskey()]);
            $data->movingstr = strip_tags(get_string('activityclipboard', '', $user->activitycopyname));
            $data->cancelcopyurl = new moodle_url('/course/mod.php', ['cancelcopy' => 'true', 'sesskey' => sesskey()]);
        }

        if (empty($modinfo->sections[$section->section])) {
            return $data;
        }

        foreach ($modinfo->sections[$section->section] as $modnumber) {
            $mod = $modinfo->cms[$modnumber];
            // If the old non-ajax move is necessary, we do not print the selected cm.
            if ($showmovehere && $USER->activitycopy == $mod->id) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($mod->is_visible_on_course_page()) {
                $item = new $this->itemclass($format, $section, $mod, $this->displayoptions);
                $data = $item->export_for_template($output);
                $data->foo = 'yooohooo'; // here
                $data->cms[] = (object)[
                    'cmitem' => $data,
                    'moveurl' => new moodle_url('/course/mod.php', array('moveto' => $modnumber, 'sesskey' => sesskey())),
                ];
            }
        }

        if (!empty($data->cms)) {
            $data->hascms = true;
        }

        return $data;
    }
}

As you can see the main thing I am doing here is adding an extra property to the object that is passed to the mustache template for cmlist.
However this does not work on a course set to my custom course format. What is the piece of the puzzle that I am missing? Do I need to take an additional step to ensure that my override class is the one being called whenever the cmlist component is rendered?
Thanks!
